# В Java Swing не отображается JtextArea

Tags: java, swing

При попытке создания нового окна JFrame на нём отображается JButton, но не отображается JTextArea.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class ViewFirst extends JFrame {
    public ViewFirst() {
        JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("___");
        frame1.setSize(400,400);
        frame1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame1.setLayout(null);

        JTextArea area2 = new JTextArea();
        area2.setBounds(10, 10, 200, 300);
        frame1.add(new JScrollPane(area2));

        JButton but2 = new JButton("Выполнить");
        but2.setBounds(95, 50, 200, 30);
        frame1.add(but2);

        frame1.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полагаю проблема в том что вы не использовали `setBounds()` для `JScrollPane`.

В этом варианте стало отображаться:

```
import javax.swing.*;

    public class ViewFirst extends JFrame {
        public ViewFirst() {
            JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("___");
            frame1.setSize(400,400);
            frame1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame1.setLayout(null);
    
            JTextArea area2 = new JTextArea();
            area2.setBounds(10, 10, 200, 300);
            JScrollPane j = new JScrollPane(area2);
            j.setBounds(10,10,200,300);
            frame1.add(j);
    
            JButton but2 = new JButton("Выполнить");
            but2.setBounds(95, 50, 200, 30);
            frame1.add(but2);
    
            frame1.setVisible(true);
        }
       
        public static void main(String[] args) {
          new ViewFirst();
    }
    }
```